# Casperjs access a frame within a frame

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs, frameset

I'm using CasperJS to script a webpage that layers framesets with 2 subframes multiple times (goes to 3 layers deep in some cases). The website is some form a old version of an online email client. I'm trying to check if there are any new messages, and if there are, download any attachments.

The format of each page is always: first frame stores the login credentials, and the second frame contains actual content.

I have two needs: use a waitForSelector call to find out when the page is fully loaded, which is always multiple layers deep, and do clicks at the deepest node to find the email message.

How do I access selectors that are multiple frames deep? CasperJS makes it trivially easy to do one, but I haven't been able to get my script to reach multiple layers down.

I've tried using window object, but the CasperJS selector has been throwing errors.

```
casper.waitForSelector(window.frames[1].document.getElementById('frame[name = Frame_A ]'), {
   // when loaded do this
});
```

Comment: If the given answer solved your problem, you may [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) it. If it didn't, then please expand on what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `document` object directly in CasperJS Scripts. You should wait that frame loaded first, then switch to that frame:

```
casper.start("...", function() {
    casper.waitForSelector(frameSelector, function() {
        casper.withFrame('Frame_A', function () {
            //do something
        });
    })
});
```